# C# Excel Query Issue

Tags: c#, sql, excel, ado.net, oledb

This code works properly. But when i want to change range, gives OleDBException.

```
OleDbCommand dates = new OleDbCommand("SELECT date FROM ["Sheet1$A1:B150"] ", baglanti);
OleDbDataReader reader= dates.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    list.Add(reader["date"]);
}
```

Range Changed Version:

```
OleDbCommand dates = new OleDbCommand("SELECT date FROM ["Sheet1$A250:B350"] ", baglanti);
OleDbDataReader reader= dates.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    list.Add(reader["date"]);
}
```

EXCEPTION IS:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled by user code
ErrorCode=-2147217904
HResult=-2147217904
Message=No value is entered for one or more required parameters.
Source=Microsoft Access Database Engine
StackTrace:
konum:    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
konum:   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
konum: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
konum: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
konum: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
konum: Hasta_Bulucu.Form1.bul_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) C:\Users\Furka\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Hasta Bulucu\Hasta      Bulucu\Form1.cs içinde: satır 269
konum: System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
konum: System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
InnerException:
```

Comment: could you please add the connection string you use to initialize OledDbConnection?

Comment: @andrews OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePick.FileName.ToString() + ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'");

Comment: @andrews when i set range A1 to R250 it includes header of the sheet but A150 to R300 not including header. So sql command cannot find column names. I need to include header information to this selection. So how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Set `HDR=NO` in the connection string like:

```
OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
                         filePick.FileName.ToString() + 
";Mode=Read;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;'");
```

also try setting IMEX to 0 and 2 and try different combinations with HDR=NO.

You're right when the range is not including column names you may get the error. Therefore, you need to try reading file by column indexes, not names.

Comment: Column indexes idea makes sense. But i stuck in sql. I can't query by columnID like A, B, C .... I tried SELECT A FROM [Sheet1$]    but still throws exception (HDR=NO) @andrews

Comment: @FK yes, I thought about that but was not able to find any samples. What if you try to use R1C1 notation? Or just query columns by index like `[1]` . Also do `SELECT *` and open the result set in the debugger and try to see  what you get in column/field names in there.

Comment: @adrews finally done. It must be F1 ..... Fn not directly column name like A, B etc.. Thank you again.

Comment: @FK you're welcome! You now have enough rep for up-voting. Would appreciate if you also up vote this answer and the one we have worked on yesterday.

Comment: you got it, enjoy :)